# R cannot read Python Pandas dataframe saved in feather format

Tags: python, r, feather

I have a pandas dataframe dfwin.
[image]

And I save it to feather format hoping I can read it in R.

[image]

But R always throws the error 
"Error in openFeather(path): Invalid: Not a feather file
Traceback:

1. read_feather("./aFolder/dfwin.feather")
2. feather(path)
3. openFeather(path)"

Can someone help me here? The R code I used is below:

````
library(feather)
dfwin = read_feather('./aFolder/dfwin.feather')```
````

Comment: Development on feather in R [moved](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2019/08/08/r-package-on-cran/) to [arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/), so it's probably a versioning thing. But you might consider using parquet, which is part of arrow as well and which is well-supported by a broader range of languages.

Answer (score 29):

I had exactly the same problem and I found a solution for it by using `arrow` package in r. the following code can be used instead of `read_feather()` from feather library.

```
arrow::read_feather("./aFolder/dfwin.feather")
```

I still don't understand why the function from the feather package doesn't work but the same function from arrow package can fix the issue.

Comment: I encountered this same problem when I upgraded the python version I was using to write the feather from 3.7 to 3.8.  That might be a clue as to the cause, but it still doesn't seem to explain it. I thought the feather package called arrow underneath anyway. This solutions still works though, thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me, and but dumping my pandas datafame to parquet (`df.to_parquet(...)`) and then reading it in R with `arrow::read_parquet(...)` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pyarrow.feather as feather
feather.write_feather(dataframe, filename)
```

Then use Reza's line of code in R o read the saved feather filename.